# Бекэнд для андроид приложения

Tags: java, android, firebase, nosql

Для моего учебного проекта мне нужно написать Андроид приложение. Я учу программирование не долго, есть опыт в разработке веб приложений(Ruby on Rails) и знания Java на среднем уровне. Но никогда не работала с мобильными платформами. Поэтому это приложение будет первым.

Мне нужна база данных, чтобы хранить инфо про Юзера, Юзер может создать(+ удалить, изменить) Событие(Sporting Event). А другие Юзеры могут учавствовать в этом Событии. Также каждое событие будет иметь Чат, где можно постить инфо про Событие.

Посоветуйте новичку, что мне использовать для backend. Я слышала, что писать бэкенд на Джава очень сложно для новичка. Это правда? Могу ли я для своего проекта использовать  Firebase?  Мне нужно сделать этот проект за чуть больше чем три недели.

Если есть еще какие-нибудь советы, рекомендации, пишите.

Comment: Если знаете rails, то берите его. Ваш бэкенд на нем написать легко и развернуть на heroku бесплатно.

Comment: Писать можно на том - на чем можете! Лично для меня быстрый backend  - это Node JS хоть в основном пишу на Java. По поводу Firebase не совсем понятно, вы хотите использовать его как БД что  бы не делать backend?

Comment: @KirillStoianov  да, я хочу использовать Firebase Realtime Database  для бекэнда .

Comment: Неплохой вариант, особенно если нету времени писать бэкенд

Answer (score 6):

Лучшим решением для вас будет, действительно, использование Firebase в качестве backend'а. Можете также взглянуть на сервисы [Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/dynamodb/) или [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/s3/).